# Updating a Django list view with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm having trouble linking this together. I'm trying to build a small leaderboard app. basically users just vote things up or down. I've got everything working except I want the leaderboard itself to update in real time or close to it without having to refresh the page.

I know I need a way to basically get an updated list based on the votes and sort them by highest votes.  So I used Django rest to build an API endpoint that produces a response in the order that I want.

The next step would be to use AJAX to get that response.  I just can't figure out how to get my new list in place of the old list. I started to write my ajax request and found that I was rewriting my whole HTML template, that can't be right. Could someone provide me some direction? I might just be overthinking this. Maybe I just need an ajax request that refreshes the whole page.

I think I might be having trouble grasping "updating" the HTML classes. I don't need to append or prepend just reorder the given elements.

Or I'm totally overthinking this whole thing so another perspective may be what I need.

**View**

```
def streams_list(request):
    streams_ranked = StreamPost.objects.annotate(q_count=Count('upvotes')) \
                                        .order_by('-q_count')
    context = {
        'streams_ranked' : streams_ranked,
        'form': StreamPostForm()
    }
    return render(request, 'streams/index.html', context)
```

**Index.html** If I manually refresh this page, it works perfectly.

```
<div id='stream-list'>
  {% include 'streams/leaderboard_list.html' %}
</div>
```

**leaderboard_list.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {% for stream in streams_ranked %}
      <div class="post-list-box">
        <h1 class="stream-title">{{ stream.title }}</h1>

        <h4 class="stream-description">{{ stream.description }}</h4>

        <a class="btn btn-warning " href="{% url 'streams:detail' pk=stream.pk %}">
        View Stream</a>
        <p>comment area</p>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3 voting-buttons">
            <a class="upvote-btn" data-href='{{ stream.get_api_upvote_url }}'
            href='{{ stream.get_upvote_url }}'><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>

            <span class="upvote-count" data-href="{% url 'streams:vote-count' pk=stream.pk %}">
              {{ stream.upvotes.count }}
            </span>

            <a class="downvote-btn" data-href="{{ stream.get_api_downvote_url }}"
            href='{{ stream.get_downvote_url }}'><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></a>

            <span class="downvote-count" data-href="{% url 'streams:vote-count' pk=stream.pk %}">
                {{ stream.downvotes.count }}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX/JS**

```
$('#stream-list').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
      $('#stream-list').html(data);
    }, error: function(error){
      console.log(error)
      console.log("error")
    }
  })
});
```

**Update Final Working Code**

**Templates**
**index**

```
<div id='stream-list'>
  <tbody class='table_body'>
  {% include 'streams/leaderboard_list.html' %}
  </tbody>
</div>
```

**leaderboard_list.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {% for stream in streams_ranked %}
      <div class="post-list-box">
        <h1 id="stream-title">{{ stream.title }}</h1>

        <h4 id="stream-description">{{ stream.description }}</h4>

        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'streams:detail' pk=stream.pk %}">
        View Stream</a>
        <p>comment area</p>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3 voting-buttons">
            <a class="upvote-btn" data-api-upvote='{{ stream.get_api_upvote_url }}'
            href='{{ stream.get_upvote_url }}'><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>

            <span id="upvote-count" data-upvotes="{% url 'streams:vote-count' pk=stream.pk %}">
              {{ stream.upvotes.count }}
            </span>


            <a class="downvote-btn" data-api-downvote="{{ stream.get_api_downvote_url }}"
            href='{{ stream.get_downvote_url }}'><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></a>

            <span id="downvote-count" data-downvotes="{% url 'streams:vote-count' pk=stream.pk %}">
                {{ stream.downvotes.count }}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS to control displaying the updated list**

```
var refreshStream = function(){
  var getNewDataUrl = '/streams/'
    $.ajax({
        url: getNewDataUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
          $('#stream-list').replaceWith($('#stream-list',data));
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}

var total_seconds = 5; // refresh every 5 seconds

setInterval(function(){
    refreshStream();
},total_seconds * 1000);
```

**View**

```
def streams_list(request):
    streams_ranked = StreamPost.objects.annotate(q_count=Count('upvotes')) \
                                    .order_by('-q_count')
    context = {
        'streams_ranked' : streams_ranked,
        'form': StreamPostForm()
    }

    return render(request, 'streams/index.html', context)
```

Comment: I'd do the ajax request in the same view rather than an API, and then refresh the concerned part of my template. that would be my approach, did you already face it?

Comment: Ohhh ok let me mess with that. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Ok! let me know if you get stuck

Comment: ya, I guess I actually might have tried this. So if I make an AJAX call to the same view, that view produces my list of model instances. Then in my template, I actually create the for loop to list them all out. I guess I'm not sure how I would replicate that with the ajax call.

Comment: *that view produces my list of model instances* | based on the request type, if the request comes from ajax, generate a different queryset, otherwise your normal queryset

Comment: Django provides a way to check the request, `if request.is_ajax()` for CBV `if self.request.is_ajax()`

Comment: I think I got it to work! Would you mind looking at my updated view and see what you think?

Comment: I actually need to build a separate template for this new ajaxy view so I'll update this once that's done

Comment: Your view seems correct, but can be improved, do you have it worked?

Comment: Ya it does work but let me fix it. That view is basically rendering my home page so by adding the ajax is trying to render the whole page again. So I need to move some of this code into a new view that renders a specific template that will inject into this template I think. Let me fix that and I'll repost my views, template, and JS

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: See my updated code above. I also put some notes on what I've updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setInterval` to refresh the concerned page of HTML every specific second.

```
var refreshStream = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/url_to_view/',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            $('#stream-list').replaceWith($('#stream-list',data));
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}

var total_seconds = 5; // refresh every 5 seconds

setInterval(function(){
    refreshStream();
},total_second * 1000);
```

Keep your view the way it was:

```
def streams_list(request):
    streams_ranked = StreamPost.objects.annotate(q_count=Count('upvotes')) \
                                    .order_by('-q_count')
    context = {
        'streams_ranked' : streams_ranked,
        'form': StreamPostForm()
    }

    return render(request, 'streams/leaderboard_list.html', context)
```

Comment: well, shoot, I was close, this does work and refreshes exactly what I need. I've got something else with my actual like and dislike buttons causing another error but this does solve the current issue. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! if you get stuck, just ask another question. I'm always around following the tag `Django`

Comment: So this is actually working until the auto refresh happens, it is refreshing the order, but once the auto refresh happens, all my links get disabled almost as if they are being removed from the DOM.

Comment: disregard for now, I think I had some other javascript wrong and I believe I've fixed it.

Comment: do you have links triggered with javascript? if it is, that's why all these links are disabled. `$(document).on('click',''class_or_id,function(){})` that way will work, rather than `$('class_or_id').click(function(){})`

Comment: well in another JS file, I have two more ajax calls to retrieve the count and to add/remove votes. I think I need to take the weekend and dive into JS and Jquery as clearly I don't know enough about either. I think I have this working for now though.

Comment: That was my issue, changing my click events to $(document).on('click', 'class', function() {}) worked. Pretty sure it's good now.